# Calling both a base constructor and a parameterless constructor?

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

Here's something that struck me, and I'm wondering if this is at all possible.

To make a long story short - here's the code:

```
public class NotificationCollection : ObservableCollection<Notification>
{
    public NotificationCollection() : base()
    {
        this.CollectionChanged += NotificationCollection_CollectionChanged;
        this.PropertyChanged += NotificationCollection_PropertyChanged;
    }

    public NotificationCollection(IEnumerable<Notification> items)
        : base(items)
    {
        this.CollectionChanged += NotificationCollection_CollectionChanged;
        this.PropertyChanged += NotificationCollection_PropertyChanged;
    }
(....)
}
```

As you can see, I'm duplicating code. Had I not been creating an inherited class, I'd write

```
public NotificationCollection(IEnumerable<Notification> items)
    : this() //I can just call the empty constructor
{
    //do stuff here...
    //however, in case of inheritance this would be handled by base(items)
}
```

So, my question is - can I call both the `base` class constructor as well as `this` constructor?

Comment: Wait... why are you subscribing to your own events? that should be a red flag...

Comment: But to answer your question, no you cannot delegate to two constructors from a single constructor.

Comment: Good point (to everyone who mentioned) about subscribing to my own events. Admittedly, it's a minor thing in a small change in a small project, so I wasn't really paying much attention. >_<

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: No, you can't.

Workaround:

```
public NotificationCollection() : this(Enumerable.Empty<Notification>())
{
}

public NotificationCollection(IEnumerable<Notification> items)
    : base(items)
{
    this.CollectionChanged += NotificationCollection_CollectionChanged;
    this.PropertyChanged += NotificationCollection_PropertyChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can only chain to *one* constructor - either in the current type (`this(...)`) or the base type (`base(...)`). If you need to call different base-constructors in these two cases, then no - you can't share the `this()` code. You can perhaps move that code into a separate method, though, and call it from both places (assuming no `readonly` members are involved).

However, you should also prefer *not* to subscribe to your own events - that is usually a code-smell. In this case, it is probably better to check for an `override`:

```
public class NotificationCollection : ObservableCollection<Notification>
{
    public NotificationCollection() : base() {}

    public NotificationCollection(IEnumerable<Notification> items)
        : base(items) {}

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(
        NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // YOUR CODE HERE
        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
    }
    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // YOUR CODE HERE
        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
    }
}
```